# What's the difference between #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP and #113-Ubuntu SMP?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, cuda

I have two ubuntu 18.04 systems one running kernel version 4.15 and one running kernel 5.4.  The one running kernel 5.4 runs nvidia-docker / cuda 10.2 successfully while the 4.15 kernel gives an error.  This is the opposite of what I would expect since NVIDIA says that cuda version 11 is needed to support kernel 5.3 and above.

Other than the kernel version the two systems show a difference from `uname -v`:

```
node1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

node1:~$ uname -v
#46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020

node1:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-42-generic


node2:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

node2:~$ uname -v
#113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020

node2:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-112-generic
```

What is Ubuntu telling me when I do `uname -v`?  The number shown is higher for the earlier kernel.